# «Самодельный» AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-threads, android-handler

Спасибо, что читаете это.

Ни для кого не секрет, что AsyncTask устарел. Этот факт разочаровал и воодушевил меня одновременно: с одной стороны, он был для меня единственным решением многих задач, с другой стороны, нужно было сделать что-нибудь подобное, используя неустаревающие потоки.

Я сделал то, что неплохо работает **для меня**. Так как я не смог найти простые ответы на свои вопросы, приведу код моего творения, для того чтобы вы помогли мне выявить если не все, то хотя бы многие недочёты в реализации.

Предупреждаю сразу, код мой очень простой, но меня больше всего беспокоят обработчики, поэтому хотелось бы в ваших ответах увидеть что-либо об их недостатках (неожиданные ошибки или утечки памяти - мне всё будет полезно).

```
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.os.Looper;

public class BackgroundTask {

    private final Handler ui = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    public void execute() {
        final HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("AsyncTask");
        thread.start();
        final Handler handler = new Handler(thread.getLooper());
        final Runnable pre = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                onStart();
            };
        };
        final Runnable post = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                onFinish();
                thread.interrupt();
                handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
                ui.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
            };
        };
        final Runnable run = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ui.post(pre);
                doInBackground();
                ui.post(post);
            };
        };
        handler.post(run);
    };

    public void publish() {
        ui.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                onPublishProgress();
            };
        });
    };

    protected void onStart() {
    };

    protected void doInBackground() {
    };

    protected void onFinish() {
    };

    protected void onPublishProgress() {
    };
}
```

Спасибо.

P.S. я всегда буду считать себя новичком в программировании под Android, потому что невозможно всеобъемлюще его знать (отсюда-то и такие глупые вопросы).

P.P.S. буду рад увидеть комментарии об оформлении. Думается мне, что это может выглядеть лучше.

Comment: *"код мой очень простой"* - месье шутник? Тут дичайший замес, с созданием нового потока и 4 неименованных вариантов `Runnable`. И вообще, складывается ощущение, что вы путаете асинхронность и многопоточность.

Comment: @user7860670, подскажите, пожалуйста, это моя запутанность видна в коде или в вопросе? По-моему, выполняются последовательные задачи: 1 в главном потоке, 1 в отдельном (HandlerThread) и ещё 1 снова в пользовательском

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А кто сказал, что `AsyncTask` устарел?  Далее собственно замечания к коду:

1. `AsyncTask` для выполнения задачи умеет его самостоятельно разбивать на несколько потоков, а ваш держит все в одном потоке.
2. Есть проблема с потоками `pre/run/post` нет гарантии, что например `run` будет выполнен строго после `pre`, а `post` будет выполнен строго после `run` - в итоге будет каша
3. `BackgroundTask` надо декларировать как `abstract` или `interface` иначе его практическая ценность непонятна - ну то есть непонятно как его использовать.
4. Вы зря останавливаете `HandlerThread` через `interrupt()` (мало того, что при это не ловите эксепшн) - православный способ через `quit()`

Вообще надо смотреть как эта конструкция будет работать в реале, трудно вот так сразу с ходу говорить. Нужно отладчиком пройтись - вы это сами то делали?

Comment: 1. Разве [здесь](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) не говорится об устаревании AsyncTask?  2. Я подозревал, что оно так будет, придётся переделать.  3. Как AsyncTask: `ClassName extends BackgroundTask`.    4. Учту.  Спасибо за ответ

Comment: Вопрос по второму пункту. Я понимаю, что `post` и `doInBackground` могут выполниться не последовательно, это не страшно (я только поручаю обработчику выполнить нужный код, а дальше сразу же выполняется `doInBackground`). Но как `post` может выполниться до `doInBackground`?

Comment: Согласен, погорячился `post()` не может выполнится до `doInBackground()`, но `pre()` то ведь точно может выполниться после `doInBackground()` - а это как бы не очень хорошо